# How to use JavaScript function after jQuery.load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to call the `draw()` function when my `"#livemap"` `li` element is clicked. The `$("#livemap").click()` works fine but `draw()` doesn't.

`draw()` does work fine when I start the app with the html from `livemap.php` inside `"#content"` instead.

This leads me to believe that the `document.getElementbyId("a")` in `draw()` doesn't yet know that `"a"` exists in the HTML... So what do I do about it?

**index.html:**

```
<head>
    <script>
        draw(){
            var a = document.getElementById("a");
            var b = a.getContext("2d");
            var mydiv = document.getElementById("canvascont");

            ...
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#livemap").click(function(){
                $("#content").load("livemap.php");
                draw();
            });

        ...

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Title image and nav bar here-->
    ...
    <li><a id="livemap"><img  src ="images/icons/1429420112_icon-map-128.png"/>Map</a>
    ...

    <!-- My main content-->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**livemap.php:**

```
<div id="canvascont">
    <canvas id="a" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var b = a.getContext("2d");
        b.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        b.fillRect(2, 2, 10, 10); 
    </script>
</div>
```

Any direction on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Oops. My actual code did in fact have "function draw()". I just didn't include "function" when I threw it up on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `draw()` function is being called right after the `$().load()` started, which means it its not waiting until the load completes, and thus cannot yet access whatever the `$().load()` loads.

So, try:

```
$("#content").load("livemap.php", function () {
    draw();
});
```

This will make the `draw()` only be called after the `$().load()` of `"livemap.php"` completes.

---

Also your declaration of `draw()` is wrong. Use `function draw() { ... }` and not `draw() { ... }`. Here's the end snippet:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function draw() {                                          // this line changed
            var a = document.getElementById("a");
            var b = a.getContext("2d");
            var mydiv = document.getElementById("canvascont");

            ...
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#livemap").click(function() {
                $("#content").load("livemap.php", function () {    // this line changed
                    draw();                                        // this line changed
                });                                                // this line changed
            });

        ...

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I ended up actually having `function draw()`, just messed up and didn't have it in my code on here.  Your other suggestion solved my problem though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

`var draw = function() {}`

Also why not combine your scripts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var draw = function() {
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var b = a.getContext("2d");
        var mydiv = document.getElementById("canvascont");

        ...
    }

    $("#livemap").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("livemap.php");
        draw();
    });
....
```